# Search between dates

Tags: php, mysql, search

I have a rather tricky search function that allows the user to search on one or more variables:

```
$where = [];

if( isset( $_POST['destination_search'] )){
$where[] = "`destination` LIKE '%" . mysql_real_escape_string( $_POST['destination_search'] ) . "%'";
}
if( isset( $_POST['cargo_search'] )){
$where[] = "`cargo` LIKE '%" . mysql_real_escape_string( $_POST['cargo_search'] ) . "%'";
}
if( isset( $_POST['dueDate_search_last'] )){
$where[] = "`delivery_date` LIKE '%" . mysql_real_escape_string( $_POST['dueDate_search_first'] ) . "%'";
}

$whereStatement = "";
if( count($where) > 0 )
{
  $whereStatement = "AND" . implode( " AND ", $where );
}

$query_Recordset_table = "
SELECT    *
FROM      `jobs` WHERE bid_deadline >= CURDATE() AND status != 'Offer accepted'
" . $whereStatement . "
ORDER BY `destination` ASC";
```

The user enter the search terms in the following form:

```
<form id="form_searchJobs" name="form1" method="post" action="">
  <input name="destination_search" type="text" class="bb-input bb-input-large" placeholder="Destination"> <br>
  <input type="text" name="cargo_search" placeholder="Cargo" class="bb-input bb-input-large"> <br>
  <input name="dueDate_search_first" type="text" id="Due_date_from" class="bb-input bb-input-small" placeholder="Due Date (from)"/> <input name="dueDate_search_last" type="text" id="Due_date_to" class="bb-input bb-input-small" placeholder="Due Date (to)"/>
  <input type="submit" name="search" id="search" class="button3" value="Search" />
</form>
```

I have tried to make the following search queries in order to search between dates:

```
if( isset( $_POST['dueDate_search_first'], $_POST['dueDate_search_last'] )){
$where[] = "`delivery_date` BETWEEN '%" . mysql_real_escape_string( $_POST['dueDate_search_first'] ) . "%' AND '%" . mysql_real_escape_string( $_POST['dueDate_search_last'] ) . "%'";
}
```

But they doesn't return anything, and they do also keep the other search variables from working. What is wrong with my search between the query?

Comment: Echo $query_Recordset_table; and you should see what's wrong

Comment: You should not use mysql_* functions they are deprecated.

Comment: @user1825067,Firstly mysql functions are deprecated.Second thing is can you please print your sql query. i.e echo $query_Recordset_table; & give me query ?

Comment: @PHPWeblineindia it echoes either the whole row (within the pre-defined boundaries) or the row matching the searched variables.
Should I give you an example?

Comment: @user1825067, I want sql query only !

Comment: @PHPWeblineindia This i what i get from my $query_Recordset_table:
`106, Odense, Oranges, 1/2 pallet, 100, 2014-11-17, 2014-11-15`

Comment: Can you please print query & give me query not resources. i.e echo $query_Recordset_table;die;

Comment: @PHPWeblineindia Aha, okay. When I echoes $query_Recorset_table this is what i get:
`SELECT    *    FROM      "jobs" WHERE bid_deadline >= CURDATE() AND status != 'Offer accepted'        ORDER BY "destination" ASC`

Comment: @user1825067,I have posted answer please have look in to that ! I think it could resolve your issue.

Comment: @PHPWeblineindia Thank you :-) I have commented on your answer below

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't make sense:

```
`delivery_date` BETWEEN '%" . mysql_real_escape_string( $_POST['dueDate_search_first'] ) . "%' AND '%" . mysql_real_escape_string( $_POST['dueDate_search_last'] ) . "%'";
```

The `%` is used in conjunction with `LIKE`.. You can't just throw that in anywhere you feel like it.

Next,  when using `BETWEEN` you have to convert your string to a date or time that MySQL can understand. If you let users freehand type a date, chances are they're not going to type something MySQL will understand.

The way I normally go about it is, store your dates as timestamps in the database, use some kind of calendar picker JS library for your form, then convert those dates to timestamp with PHP's `strtotime()` or something. Then you can use those timestamps in your query.

Comment: The search does function when you search on single dates without converting them to strings. But when I search between dates it can't find anything.

I have now tried your suggestion:
`if( isset($_POST['deadline_search_first'], $_POST['deadline_search_last'] )){
 $deadline_date_first = strtotime($_POST['deadline_search_first']);
 $deadline_date_last = strtotime($_POST['deadline_search_last']);
    $where[] = "bid_deadline BETWEEN '%" . $deadline_date_first . "%' AND '%". $deadline_date_last . "%'";
}`
And it doesn't work either?

Answer (score 0):

```
$curdate = date('Y-m-d h:i:s');

$query_Recordset_table = "
SELECT * FROM `jobs` WHERE bid_deadline >= $curdate AND status != 'Offer accepted'
" . $whereStatement . "
ORDER BY `destination` ASC";
```

Comment: The datefields in the table are only `(Y-m-d)` So I used that instead, but then it does also show the results where bid_deadline has exceeded today (curdate).

Further, with exception of the new search function to search between dates, the query is working. There is nothing wrong with the query.
The problem is when I add the search between function (see the function above), then the rest of the search functions stop working. But the overall query is still working.